# Expex command \begingl not avalaible in encoding TU when running lualatex

Tags: errors, luatex, font-encodings, expex

When using the **expex** package for glossing examples with the \begingl enviroment and running the following document with *lualatex* the following error is obtained:

> Too many }'s.
>  \egroup

l.41 \xe

The document is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\usepackage{expex}
%Open type fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=.92}
\setmainfont[% main rm
  Ligatures=TeX,
      ItalicFont=LucidaBrightOT-Italic.otf,
        BoldFont=LucidaBrightOT-Demi.otf,
  BoldItalicFont=LucidaBrightOT-DemiItalic.otf,
  ]{LucidaBrightOT.otf}
  %
  \setsansfont[% main sans
  Ligatures=TeX,
      ItalicFont=LucidaSansOT-Italic.otf,
        BoldFont=LucidaSansOT-Demi.otf,
  BoldItalicFont=LucidaSansOT-DemiItalic.otf,
  ]{LucidaSansOT.otf}
%
\setmonofont[% main typewriter
      ItalicFont=LucidaSansTypewriterOT-Oblique.otf,
        BoldFont=LucidaSansTypewriterOT-Bold.otf,
  BoldItalicFont=LucidaSansTypewriterOT-BoldOblique.otf,
  ]{LucidaSansTypewriterOT.otf}
%
\setmathfont{LucidaBrightMathOT.otf}[BoldFont=LucidaBrightMathOT-Demi]
%

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}


\ex
\begingl
\gla Yes// 
\glb Yes//
\glft `Yes'//
\angel 
\xe

\end{document}
```

[image: \begingl with no options]

However when options are given to \begingl[everygla=,aboveglcskip=0pt,aboveglftskip=0pt,glstyle=wrap] *lualatex* runs smoothly
and correctly products the pdf output.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[a4paper]{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\usepackage{expex}
%Open type fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=.92}
\setmainfont[% main rm
  Ligatures=TeX,
      ItalicFont=LucidaBrightOT-Italic.otf,
        BoldFont=LucidaBrightOT-Demi.otf,
  BoldItalicFont=LucidaBrightOT-DemiItalic.otf,
  ]{LucidaBrightOT.otf}
  %
  \setsansfont[% main sans
  Ligatures=TeX,
      ItalicFont=LucidaSansOT-Italic.otf,
        BoldFont=LucidaSansOT-Demi.otf,
  BoldItalicFont=LucidaSansOT-DemiItalic.otf,
  ]{LucidaSansOT.otf}
%
\setmonofont[% main typewriter
      ItalicFont=LucidaSansTypewriterOT-Oblique.otf,
        BoldFont=LucidaSansTypewriterOT-Bold.otf,
  BoldItalicFont=LucidaSansTypewriterOT-BoldOblique.otf,
  ]{LucidaSansTypewriterOT.otf}
%
\setmathfont{LucidaBrightMathOT.otf}[BoldFont=LucidaBrightMathOT-Demi]
%

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}


\ex
\begingl[everygla=,aboveglcskip=0pt,aboveglftskip=0pt,glstyle=wrap]
\gla Yes// 
\glb Yes//
\glft `Yes'//
\endgl 
\xe

\end{document}
```

[image: \begingl with options]

Here is the log of the example with the error

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./minimal-expex.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-01-22>
 (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/minimal.cls
Document Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def)))
 (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-luatex.
sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/lualatex-math/lualatex-math.st
y (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.t
ex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/expex/expex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/expex/expex.tex))
(/Users/norberto/Library/texmf/tex/latex/lucidaot/LucidaBrightOT.fontspec)
(/Users/norberto/Library/texmf/tex/latex/lucidaot/LucidaSansOT.fontspec)
(/Users/norberto/Library/texmf/tex/latex/lucidaot/LucidaSansTypewriterOT.fontsp
ec) (./minimal-expex.aux)
Overfull \hbox (20.62636pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 36--39
 [][][]|\TU/LucidaBrightOT.otf(0)/m/n/10 ‘Yes’ 
./minimal-expex.tex:41: Too many }'s.
<recently read> \egroup 
        
l.41 \xe
      
? s
OK, entering \scrollmode...
[1{/Users/norberto/Library/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdfte
x.map}
Missing character: There is no ⪥ (U+2AA5) in font [LucidaBrightOT.otf]:mode=n
ode;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;!
] (./minimal-expex.aux)

 *File List*
 minimal.cls    2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
fontspec.sty    2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
  xparse.sty    2023-10-10 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2024-01-22 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-luatex.def    2024-01-04 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
fontspec-luatex.sty    2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

 fontenc.sty    2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
fontspec.cfg
unicode-math.sty    2023/08/13 v0.8r Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
unicode-math-luatex.sty    2023/08/13 v0.8r Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaT
eX
l3keys2e.sty    2023-10-10 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
  fix-cm.sty    2020/11/24 v1.1t fixes to LaTeX
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
 amsmath.sty    2023/05/13 v2.17o AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
lualatex-math.sty    2022/01/01 v1.12 Patches for mathematics typesetting with 
LuaLaTeX
etoolbox.sty    2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
   expex.sty    5/1/2017 v5.1b LaTex wrapper for expex.tex (JF)
 xkeyval.sty    2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
   expex.tex    5/25/2017 v5.1b ExPex linguistics example formatter (JF)
LucidaBrightOT.fontspec
LucidaSansOT.fontspec
LucidaSansTypewriterOT.fontspec
 ***********

)
(see the transcript file for additional information)
 462 words of node memory still in use:
   7 hlist, 2 vlist, 2 rule, 2 glue, 4 kern, 1 glyph, 7 attribute, 45 glue_spec
, 7 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:44,3:8,4:1,5:18,6:6,7:82,9:34
</Users/norberto/Library/texmf/fonts/opentype/bh/lucidaot/LucidaBrightOT.otf>
Output written on minimal-expex.pdf (1 page, 3047 bytes).
SyncTeX written on minimal-expex.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on minimal-expex.log.
```

Is there anything wrong with my tex configuration?

Best regards

Norberto

Comment: Welcome! This question is a duplicate of the linked thread. I guess that `\angel` should be `\endgl`. Don't use `minimal` for examples, but rather `article`.

Comment: Thank very you. You are right. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Worry for neither the duplicate nor the typo! That issue was very subtle and the only clue was the mysterous `Missing character: There is no ⪥ (U+2AA5)` warning!